# Fill up adjacency list of node according to its density

Tags: c#, graph

I have a List of type `Node`. I want to create a graph from this list and thus I am using adjacency list for that purpose. Each node of type `Node` has adjacency list associated with it. Here is my class `Node`

```
public class Node
{
    public int Density { get; set; }
    public InterestProfile P1 { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Neighbors { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsMessageRecvd = false;
    public Boolean IsMessageSent = false;

    public Node()
    {
        Neighbors = new List<Node>();
    }
    public Node(InterestProfile a)
    {
        Neighbors = new List<Node>();
        this.P1 = a;
    }

    public static int GetDensity(Node n)
    {
        return n.Density;
    }

}
```

And here is class `Graph`

```
public class Graph<T>
{
    List<Node> nodeSet;
    public int[] Type { get; set; }

    public Graph()
    {
    }

    public Graph(List<Node> nodeSet)
    {
        if (nodeSet == null)
            this.nodeSet = new List<Node>();
        else
            this.nodeSet = nodeSet;
    }

    public void AddNode(Node node)
    {
        nodeSet.Add(node);
    }

    public void AddEdge(Node from, Node to)
    {
        from.Neighbors.Add(to);
        to.Neighbors.Add(from);
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return nodeSet.Count;
    }
}
```

In `Main` I create graph as follows:

```
 Graph<Node> graph1 = new Graph<Node>(List1);
```

For each node in the graph, I want to create an adjacency list containing number of nodes equal to its density. Can someone help me with this? Do I have to make any changes in class `Graph` in order to achieve it?

What I am looking here is, lets say List1 has some nodes in that. Now, each node in List1 has some density associated with it. Suppose List1[0] has density 6 then, in adjacency list of List1[0], I want to add 6 nodes. But I am not sure where I should implement this.

Second thing I can do is I can define `AddNode` and `AddEdge` method in class Node itself instead of class `Graph`. So it will look something like this:

```
foreach (Node node in List1)
        {
            int count = 0, i = 0;
            while (count <= node.Density)
            {
                node.AddNode(List1[i]);
                Node.AddEdge(node, List1[i]);
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Is this right?

Comment: Is `Density` defined as `Neighbors.Length`?

Comment: Yes, you can say so. Density defines number of nodes each node is connected to.

Comment: ... then isn't the 'adjacency list` for a given `Node n` just `n.Neighbors`? Please explain if I am missing something.

Comment: I am not getting you. What I am thinking here is I want to add nodes to 'neighbors' list of each node. But I am not sure how should I do that. Should I do before I create a graph from a list or after that.

Comment: @Jashaszun Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

now do you want the output formatted? you could do something like this

```
var adjacencylist = nodeSet.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Node, List<Node>>(x, x.Neighbours));
```

Comment: What I am looking here is, lets say List1 has some nodes in that. Now, each node in List1 has some density associated with it. Suppose List1[0] has density 6 then, in adjacency list of List1[0], I want to add 6 nodes. But I am not sure where I should implement this.

Comment: how/where do you want to use it? Seems like adjacencylist as you describe is just the neightbors.

Comment: For a second lets forget about the Graph, Suppose there are methods AddNode and AddEdge in class Node itself. Then is it right?